# how can I get ipAddress info from criterion?

Tags: c#, google-ads-api, awql

I'm working with Google Adwords and currently can't get specific info. On my Adwords account I set 'IP address exclusion' with 3 IPs. I want to get this IPs from my code:

```
AdWordsUser user = new AdWordsUser();
var campaignService = (CampaignCriterionService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201506.CampaignCriterionService);
int offset = 0;
        int pageSize = 500;

        var page = new CampaignCriterionPage();
        String awql = "SELECT Id where IsNegative = true ORDER BY Id ASC LIMIT " + offset + "," + pageSize;
try
        {
            do
            {   
                page = campaignService.query(awql);

                // Display the results.
                if (page != null && page.entries != null)
                {
                    int i = offset;
                    foreach (var item in page.entries)
                    {
                        var t = item; //my work logic here ....                           
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                offset += pageSize;
            } while (offset < page.totalNumEntries);
            Debug.WriteLine("Number of items found: {0}", page.totalNumEntries);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new System.ApplicationException("Failed to retrieve campaigns", e);
        }
```

Query returns number of resuls: 3, but without actual info about ipAddress( ipAddress contains null) .

what can I do?

Comment: Hi, don't have the solution to your question, but maybe you could easier debug your query with https://www.awql.me, a free tool to see the result of AWQL query. There is an online help and a helper to build the queries.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate for your suggestion. Currently, I've found a workaround for this problem and I work on another part of my development.  Have a nice work!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not believe that AWQL provides a selector for the Address of a blocked IP. In any case, it is certainly NOT supplied with the AWQL statement you have used above which is only bringing back the Id field:

> ```
> String awql = "SELECT Id where IsNegative = true ORDER BY Id ASC LIMIT " + offset + "," + pageSize; try
> ```

This is why the value is null in your response.

The only way I believe it is possible is to get your hands dirty with the `Selector` and `Predicate` objects for that service and use the `get()` method rather than the `query()` one.

This solution works for me (admittedly with a later version of the API)

```
var campaignCriterionService = (CampaignCriterionService)user.GetService(AdWordsService.v201601.CampaignCriterionService);
int offset = 0;
int pageSize = 500;

var page = new CampaignCriterionPage();

try
{
    do
    {
        page = campaignCriterionService.get(new Selector
        {
            fields = new string[] { IpBlock.Fields.Id, IpBlock.Fields.IpAddress },
            predicates = new Predicate[]
            {
                new Predicate
                {
                    field = IpBlock.Fields.CriteriaType,
                    @operator = PredicateOperator.EQUALS,
                    values = new string[] { "IP_BLOCK" }
                }
            }
        });

        // Display the results.
        if (page != null && page.entries != null)
        {
            int i = offset;
            foreach (var item in page.entries)
            {
                var t = item; //my work logic here ....                           
                i++;
            }
        }
        offset += pageSize;
    } while (offset < page.totalNumEntries);
    Debug.WriteLine("Number of items found: {0}", page.totalNumEntries);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new System.ApplicationException("Failed to retrieve campaigns", e);
}
```